# notification does not get feedback from apps

Tags: notifications

since a little while (perhaps a week or two, three maybe) my notification don't disappear if I go to the app that caused the notification.

Example: I enter `sleep 10 ; echo 'hallo'` in a terminal and go and do something else. After 10s there will be a notification `Task finished`. If I now go to the terminal, it used to be that the notification disappeared, but now the notification remains.

Did I accidentially change something in my setup? Or is there some other way this can happen?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that too.
It would be nice, if notification will disappear again after open the app.

Or on other hand, if I click on the notification it should open the app.